# Check registry keys of a Software that is already installed in your system For WIX setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wix, prerequisites

I have a WIX setup. I want to promt message box for some prerequisites before installing my setup.
I am using below code to check registry keys for a particular software.
But it always prompt a message weather a software is installed or not.

```
<Condition Message="This application requires ReportViewer.">
      <![CDATA[ReportViewerV10 OR ReportViewerWow64V10]]>
    </Condition>

    <util:RegistrySearch
     Root="HKLM"
     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ReportViewer\v10.0"
     Value="Install"
     Variable="ReportViewerV10"
     Win64="yes"
  />
    <util:RegistrySearch
    Root="HKLM"
    Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ReportViewer\v10.0"
    Value="Install"
    Variable="ReportViewerWow64V10"
    Win64="yes"/>
```

Can anyone guide me where i am doing wrong?
What should be registry keys for a software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/read_a_registry_entry.html) you don't have your Registry search parameters set up quite right.  The following should yield better results.

```
<Property Id="NReportViewerV10">
    <RegistrySearch Id="NetFramework20"
                Root="HKLM"
                Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ReportViewer\v10.0"
                Name="Install"
                Type="raw" />
</Property>
<Property Id="ReportViewerWow64V10">
    <RegistrySearch Id="NetFramework20"
                Root="HKLM"
                Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ReportViewer\v10.0"
                Name="Install"
                Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.I will try by this.But
I am also unable to read registry keys for any software.That may be the reason of not working.
Could you  help me how can i get registry keys for any installed software in Registry Editor(Regedit)..:)

Comment: I would suggest taking the or logic out and just testing for one of the packages to make sure it works first.  Please test one and then get back to me and we can go from there.

Comment: YES THAT WORKS For me but still i am unable to get the correct registry keys for a installed software.
I am able to find keys for Report viewer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you are asking...Can you not see the registry key for the package you are installing?

Comment: I want to know from where i can get correct registry keys for a already installed software?
In my one setup i need to check Bonjour(An Apple Software) as a prerequisites.
To check wheather it is installed on my system or not i need its registry key. But i am not able to achieve its registry key.

Comment: I don't know of anyway other than searching the registry on a computer it is installed manually.